# How to fix annoying Android Emulator Configuration window scroll glitch?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

Ever since I installed Android Studio, I'm already experiencing this. I can't see the remaining options below. Every time I scroll down, this happens.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lT71c.png)